# Is port 445 enough for SMB?

Tags: networking, smb

I have a [ssh tunnel](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example) from my Windows 10 machine to a Linux server (`192.168.10.2` in a LAN, with port 22 exposed on the Internet and forwarded there) that also serves SMB.

I tried to forward my local `127.0.0.3:445` to that server and map `\\127.0.0.3`. This fails with "Windows cannot access `\\127.0.0.3`.

On the flip side, when I am in the network where `192.168.10.2` is, I have no problems mapping `\\192.168.10.2`.

This would suggests that in order to map a share I need more than just access to the port `445`. Is that correct?

EDIT: as a side note, other ports going through that tunnel are fine (HTTPS, MQTT, ...)

Comment: @Spiff: thanks, updated. No, I checked the ports because I work a lot with 443 (HTTPS) and made sure to not make the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, modern SMB (especially v2/v3) runs only on TCP port 445. However, Windows clients may also expect the server to be pingable, i.e. respond to ICMP Echo, before they even attempt a SMB connection.

Also, it  *could* be that Windows implicitly maps all local address to a magic loopback connection that bypasses the TCP/IP stack entirely and is therefore unaware of your SSH tunnel. I would definitely recommend an IP-level VPN instead.

<sub>Only very old clients, Windows 9x era and older, will expect TCP port 139 instead (and *possibly* the NetBIOS Datagram service on UDP 137-138).</sub>

<sub>Recently, Microsoft has announced an experimental SMB-over-QUIC which can use UDP port 443 as alternative. This is not yet publicly available.</sub>

Comment: The server is pingable (127.0.0.3 at least). As for the VPN, my setup is there because of a VPN connection that cannot have another one on top.